# DB connection(cx_Oracle) function calling from another function gives "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cusror'"

Tags: oracle, windows-10, python-3.8

I have two python files and each have one function :

a.py (This function is for oracle db connection)

```
def db_conection(username,password,dbname,encoding):
    # print(username,password,dbname,encoding)
    try:
         connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, dbname, encoding=encoding)

        # show the version of the Oracle Database
         print(connection.version)
    except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        # release the connection
        if connection:
            connection.close()
```

b.py

```
from a import *



def set_schema(user):
    con = db_conection(username,password,dbname,encoding)
    cur = con.cursor()
    print(user)
    cur.execute("""alter session set current_schema = {}""".format(user))
    cur.close()


user = "ABCDE"
set_schema(user)
```

The problem/error i am facing when i try to execute set_schema function(b.py)

```
           cur = con.cursor()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

if i just run below statment in b.py for set_schema function it works

```
db_conection(username,password,dbname,encoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct "solution" is:

```
# a.py

def db_conection(username,password,dbname,encoding):
    try:
         connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, dbname, encoding=encoding)
        # show the version of the Oracle Database
         print(connection.version)
         return connection
    except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
        print(error)
```

and

```
# b.py     

from a import *

def set_schema(user):
    con = db_conection(username,password,dbname,encoding)
    con.current_schema = user  # more efficient then executing ALTER

user = "ABCDE"
set_schema(user)
```

Of course, once `db_connection()` has finished the connection will be closed, but hopefully you just gave example code to show your problem.  You may want to look at [subclassing](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/Subclassing.py).

If you are running multi-user, you could use a [connection pool](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ConnectionPool.py) and use a [session callback](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/SessionCallback.py) to set session attributes.

Comment: @Christoper Jones I am still getting the same error.I edited my original post as well

Comment: @Christoper Jones I am not running multi user.Actually I am login with my id on DB and then doing some operations/action on other user id for e.g lock/unlock users and some other operations mainly related to users